# Wordpress : exclude children posts from next_post_link, keep only parents

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I'm having an issue using `WP built-in` functions : `'next_post_link'` and `'previous_post_link'`.
My theme uses a custom post type `"project"` and every project post has children :

- Project 1

  - subpost 1
  - subpost 2
  - subpost 3
- Project 2

  - subpost 1
  - subpost 2
  - subpost 3
- ... etc

My problem is that when I use `"next_post_link"`, the button links to a child post `(ex: subpost 1)`. I want it to link only to a parent project item (ex: project 2).

```
<?php
query_posts('post_type=projet&post_status=publish&name='.$postname);
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) :
        the_post();
        global $post;
        previous_post_link(); // output a link to a sub-project
        next_post_link(); // output a link to a sub-project
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link), you can specify the next_post_link() to lead to the "next post in the current taxonomy term". Assign a category to your custom post type, maybe "projects" and try this:

```
<?php
query_posts('post_type=projet&post_status=publish&name='.$postname);
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) :
        the_post();
        global $post;
        previous_post_link($in_same_cat = true, $taxonomy = 'project'); // output a link to a sub-project
        next_post_link($in_same_cat = true, $taxonomy = 'project'); // output a link to a sub-project
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I thought about this solution but I'm looking for another way to do it, I dont want my client to check multiple categories.